# MySQL: Can this Join query be optimized?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have two tables. create command for those tables are as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice` (
  `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `VersionNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CreationDate` datetime default NULL,
  `ModificationDate` datetime default NULL,
  `CreateBy` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `ModifyBy` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `BusinessId` varchar(255) character set utf8 default NULL,
  `Status` int(11) default NULL,
  `VendorId` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `CustomerId` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `OrderDate` date default NULL,
  `ExpectedDate` date default NULL,
  `DeliveryDate` date default NULL,
  `InvoiceFor` int(11) default NULL,
  `Reference` varchar(255) character set utf8 default NULL,
  `Agent` varchar(255) character set utf8 default NULL,
  `BnAgent` varchar(255) character set utf8 default NULL,
  `Note` varchar(255) character set utf8 default NULL,
  `HasVoucher` char(1) character set utf8 default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Id`),
  KEY `CustomerId` (`CustomerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `invoiceitem` (
  `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `VersionNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CreationDate` datetime default NULL,
  `ModificationDate` datetime default NULL,
  `CreateBy` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `ModifyBy` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `BusinessId` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `Status` int(11) default NULL,
  `InvoiceId` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `ProductId` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `PackageQty` decimal(19,5) default NULL,
  `PackagePrice` decimal(19,5) default NULL,
  `ItemPerPackage` decimal(19,5) default NULL,
  `ItemQty` decimal(19,5) default NULL,
  `ItemPrice` decimal(19,5) default NULL,
  `StoreQty` decimal(19,5) default NULL,
  `RevenuePercent` decimal(19,5) default NULL,
  `PurchasePrice` decimal(19,5) default NULL,
  `Vat` decimal(19,5) default NULL,
  `TotalAmount` decimal(19,5) default NULL,
  `InvoiceItemFor` int(11) default NULL,
  `LifeTimeUptoDate` datetime default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Id`),
  KEY `invoiceid_productid` (`InvoiceId`,`ProductId`),
  KEY `ProductId` (`ProductId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_invoiceitem` FOREIGN KEY (`InvoiceId`) REFERENCES `invoice` (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

---

**Purpose of this query**
I have to show the list of invoices to the admin. He need to see the invoice date, Invoice number, customer Id, Product id and if the customer take that product previously then that previous date.

**Now the Query**

```
SELECT iv.id, iv.CustomerId, ii.ProductId, MAX(iv2.orderdate) AS PriviousDate
FROM invoice AS iv
INNER JOIN invoice AS iv2 
    ON iv.CustomerId=iv2.CustomerId 
    AND iv.OrderDate>iv2.OrderDate
INNER JOIN invoiceItem AS ii 
    ON iv.id=ii.invoiceId 
INNER JOIN invoiceItem AS ii2 
    ON  iv2.id=ii2.invoiceId 
    AND ii.ProductId=ii2.ProductId
WHERE iv.Status=0 
    AND ii.Status=0 
    AND iv2.Status=0 
    AND ii2.Status=0
GROUP BY ii.ProductId, iv.CustomerId
```

Here iv.id and ii.id is primary key
customerId and Productid fields are also indexes 
and invoiceId is the foreginkey (iv.id=ii.invoiceId )

I am running this query in my MySql server (local)
But Most of the time I got timeout. How can I optimized this query?

the Explain for this query is as follows:
[image]

now I apply

```
create index invoiceid_productid 
  on invoiceItem(invoiceId, productId)
```

after that the explain result is 
[image]

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the tables?  If so, then please post the details.

Comment: Have you properly defined `FOREIGN KEY` constraints where appropriate?

Comment: Here iv.id and ii.id is primary key customerId and Productid fields are also indexes and invoiceId is the foreginkey (iv.id=ii.invoiceId )

Comment: I would recommend you to go through [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/ex_plan.htm#PFGRF009), this would help you in understanding the explain plan and optimizing your query eventually.

Comment: why do you need this query ? it doesn't seem to usefull. it's just a carthesian product of your invoice and invoiceItem tables... what should it return ?

Comment: Please explain the purpose of this query

Comment: I added the purpose of this query. it will return the invoice list with a previous taken date.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `EXPLAIN` results, the problem is clearly the `invoiceItem` table. It has 200,000 rows, and MySQL isn't using any indexes to access it.

So you should look at creating indexes to speed access to it.

I mocked up your tables:

```
create table invoice (
  id int auto_increment not null,
  customerid int not null,
  orderdate timestamp not null,
  status int default 0 not null,
  primary key(id)
);
create table invoiceItem (
  id int auto_increment not null,
  invoiceId int not null,
  productId int not null,
  status int default 0 not null,
  primary key (id)
);
```

I created these indexes:

```
create index invoiceId on invoiceItem(invoiceId);
create index cod on invoice(customerid, orderdate);
create index stat on invoice(status);
```

My EXPLAIN (on empty tables) now has all tables using type `ref`.

You can also see this [tutorial](http://schimpf.es/mysql-explain-tutorial/) which is for MySQL ;-)

Comment: I apply that code and upload the explain result in the main post

Comment: Thanks - it didn't seem to make much of a difference, though, did it?

Comment: Could you perhaps upload the CREATE statements for each of these tables?

Comment: I uploaded my table structures.

Answer (score 0):

Not much here (it would have been helpful to see what you're indexes are) but assuming the invoice ids increase in line with invoice date....I suspect this might be slightly faster:

```
SELECT iv.id, iv.CustomerId, ii.ProductId, MAX(iv2.orderdate) AS PriviousDate
FROM invoice AS iv
INNER JOIN invoice AS iv2 
   ON iv.CustomerId=iv2.CustomerId 
   AND iv.id>iv2.id
INNER JOIN invoiceItem AS ii 
   ON iv.id=ii.invoiceId 
INNER JOIN invoiceItem AS ii2 
   ON  iv2.id=ii2.invoiceId 
   AND ii.ProductId=ii2.ProductId
   AND ii.invoiceId>ii2.invoiceId
WHERE iv.Status=0 
   AND ii.Status=0 
   AND iv2.Status=0 
   AND ii2.Status=0
GROUP BY ii.ProductId, iv.CustomerId
```

But you really need an index on ProductId, Status and InvoiceId in the invoiceItem table before it's going to be appreciable faster.